# Jmeter - How to make threads to perform the action at the same time

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, delay, performance-testing

How can we make the threads to start the thread :Next at the same time. I tried with synchronizing timer as child on SM_check but the thread samples :Next  were not processed at the same time. synchronizing timer on the thread group makes all the samples at once, but I need to have the threads to be on the same time from :Next only. Any help on this is much appreciated.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g82j.png)

Thread Group

```
CSV Data set config

User Defined Variables

Loop Controller

: HTTP Cookie Manager

: Login

:SM

:SM_Check

    :- HTTP Header Manager
    :- Synchronizing Timer
    :- View Results tree

:Next tag
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current configuration assumes that threads are grouped (executed at the same time) for `:SM_Check`.

If your target is to execute `:Next` sampler with all threads at the same time - move the Synchronizing Timer to be a **child** of the `:Next` sampler.

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) article for a little bit more detailed explanation